# can we sort result of group() in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have one scenario like need to sort the result of group() in mongoDB

For Example:

Suppose you have documents in Student collection like below

```
    {
    "id":"kjdkfdjkljflkd73847",
    "DepartementID":123,
    "parties":[
            {
              "idNumber" : "103",
              "studentName" : {
                "suffix" : "Mr",
                "firstName" : "ram",
                "middleName" : "",
                "lastName" : "gorli"
                       }
           },
            {
              "idNumber" : "99",
              "studentName" : {
                "suffix" : "Mr",
                "firstName" : "ramesh",
                "middleName" : "",
                "lastName" : "vogue"
                       }
           },
              ]
          },
    {
    "id":"kjdkfdjkljflkd73847",
    "DepartementID":123,
    "parties":[
            {
              "idNumber" : "101",
              "studentName" : {
                "suffix" : "Mr",
                "firstName" : "Mike",
                "middleName" : "",
                "lastName" : "john"
                       }
           },
            {
              "idNumber" : "102",
              "studentName" : {
                "suffix" : "Mr",
                "firstName" : "ram", 
                "middleName" : " ",
                "lastName" : "gorli"
                       }
           },
              ]
      }
```

I'm grouping the details by using DepartmentID in student collection, In group() itself I need to sort by using last name in parties. how can we achieve this in one query it self?

please help me out. I really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: first `$unwind` parties, then `$sort` on lastName and finally group using `$first`

Comment: i'm new to MongoDB..can you please give me the example query to my scenario. that will really help me alot

Comment: take a look at [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)

Comment: yes..I tried what you suggested..but it's giving 4 results but in my case it should display two results within the result parties should be sorted by lastname

Comment: add what you have so far and I'll help you fix it

Comment: `db.getCollection('students').aggregate( [ 
                                { $unwind: "$parties" },
                                {$sort:{"parties.name.lastName":1}},
                                {$group:{_id:"$DepartementID",
                                    first:{"$first":"$DepartementID"},
                                    Students: {$push: "$$ROOT"}
                                }},
] )`

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you :

```
db.getCollection('quotes').aggregate([  
   {  
      $unwind:"$parties"
   },
   {  
      $sort:{  
         "parties.studentName.lastName": 1
      }
   },
   {  
      $group:{  
         _id:"$DepartementID",
         parties:{  
            $push:"$parties"
         }
      }
   }
])
```